# WordPress Custom Post types and Taxonomy relationships best practices

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Given that a Custom Post Type (CPT) has properties geared towards a UI on the front end and a taxonomy is a data object which allows for easy association of a post type and a set of terms (which can then be displayed on an archive page),

**which is the best to use when, say, linking a CPT** (e.g. a product, product review and then its author?)

### Current thought process:

As a newbie to development, I assume that if I set the option to enable reviews only allowed by registered users, it would then link the Author profile as the user and thus return the users default profile page should someone click on author after reading a review. Respectively a product page is where the review is made so it's already being displayed. This puts it in the Taxonomy realm as it is tied to that product and not searchable as its own object (not looking for the factual truth about products and reviews but the idea of the author and product being linked via the review).

Similarly, what if I wanted to use a star rating that the reviewer could add to or attribute to a product only instead of the number of stars they would apply the appropriate tag like descriptions. These could then be displayable and searchable.

**Is it then the best to use a taxonomy for the stars, to link the products and the Authors?**

OR

**Is it the best to create CPTs for everything and link them directly skipping the taxonomy all together?**  (if possible)

I'm asking because I'm have trouble in the planning of my project. I don't expect a simple answer. I'm just not sure how to visualize a structure of the pre existing WP data types and where they would relate to certain aspects of engagement and use.

How do I determine when the use of taxonomy vs. CPT vs. Meta field vs. custom field etc. are appropriate?

What are the rule of thumbs you can use to determine how best to proceed?
The more I think about it, it feels like a rabbit hole of further and deeper linking and linking between one piece of data or the next. Where to stop?